# Unable to find element either way in Selenium

Tags: selenium

Below is the link to which I am trying to click but it is showing -- no such element present exception error:

```
<a href="/productExt/control/main?externalLoginKey=EL9c14f06c-615d-443f-adb7-781cb5624438" title="Product">Product</a>
```

First I tried: `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Product")).click();`

It was working earlier but now not working.
Other than above I tried XPath and CSS selector but none is working.

Comment: Run your test again and see if this find element command runs before the page completely loaded and this link is visible. If it was working before then this might occur due to the delay in loading

Comment: provide the full html code for this scenario and exception that your getting ? and tag the language also

Comment: When you _remove anchor tag_ and other relevant information debugging becomes much difficult. Update the question with the relevant _HTML_, your _code block_ and error stack trace.

Comment: How is going? Did you try my answer?